# silverlight full screen

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, fullscreen

i use silverlight fullscreen changing normally when i click the fullsceen and exit fullscreen button 
But when i change it through code without clicking 
it do the exit but not the fullscreen, which means false is working true doesn't work. Any ideas ??

Comment: does it has to be targeting through a button click ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes going to full screen must occur in the context a user action like a button click.  An application can not go fullscreen from just any code.

Otherwise such an app could go full screen on load and constantly keep making itself fullscreen regarless of the users wishes and thus make a real nusience of itself.